# How to write Russian text in a file?

Tags: languages, write-file

I am writing Russian text in a file but it gives the error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\indexfile
\openout\indexfile=\jobname.index

\write\indexfile{Патологическая миопия является видом высокой степени близору^\thepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't include to file any text, so there's no dvi-output & no output at all. Add some text and you will get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `\write` is subject to expansion, but you don't want to expand the active characters LaTeX uses for implementing UTF-8 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
x % in order to shipout something
\newwrite\indexfile
\openout\indexfile=\jobname.index

\write\indexfile{%
  \unexpanded{Патологическая миопия является видом высокой степени близору}, \thepage}
\end{document}
```

In “classical” LaTeX, that is, without e-TeX extensions (which should be available by default unless you're running a very old TeX distribution), it would be

```
\toks0={Патологическая миопия является видом высокой степени близору}%
\write\indexfile{\the\toks0, \thepage}
```

Note that we want to keep `\thepage` outside the scope of `\unexpanded`.

Answer (score 0):

After the following changes *.index is not empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

%\usepackage{Sweave} % I haven't it. Meaningless for the question, I hope - PS
\begin{document}
\newwrite\indexfile
%\openout\indexfile=\jobname.index
\immediate\openout\indexfile=\jobname.index

%\write\indexfile{Патологическая миопия является видом высокой степени близору^\thepage}
\immediate\write\indexfile{Патологическая миопия является видом высокой степени близору^\thepage}
\end{document}
```

It contains:

```
\T2A\CYRP \T2A\cyra \T2A\cyrt \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrl \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrg \T2A\cyri \T2A\cyrch \T2A\cyre \T2A\cyrs \T2A\cyrk \T2A\cyra \T2A\cyrya  \T2A\cyrm \T2A\cyri \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrp \T2A\cyri \T2A\cyrya  \T2A\cyrya \T2A\cyrv \T2A\cyrl \T2A\cyrya \T2A\cyre \T2A\cyrt \T2A\cyrs \T2A\cyrya  \T2A\cyrv \T2A\cyri \T2A\cyrd \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrm  \T2A\cyrv \T2A\cyrery \T2A\cyrs \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrk \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrishrt  \T2A\cyrs \T2A\cyrt \T2A\cyre \T2A\cyrp \T2A\cyre \T2A\cyrn \T2A\cyri  \T2A\cyrb \T2A\cyrl \T2A\cyri \T2A\cyrz \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrr \T2A\cyru ^1
```

Comment: I am also getting some \IeC {\cyra }\IeC {\cyrs }\IeC {\cyrt }\IeC {\cyrm }\IeC {\cyra } (\IeC {\cyrn }\IeC {\cyra } these character when i use this code in Sweave. May i know what do these all character mean?

Comment: can't we write in text format instead of above format.